# To choose a specific certificate among many

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I have 2 certificates (same hostname but issued from different CAs) installed for the same application on a server (lets say from domain A). however they are supposed to being used for authenticating with 2 different servers from 2 different domains (B and C). Problem is, both servers are trying to fetch the same cert which causes one domain to pop error since the CA trusted in one domain (B) is not trusted in the other (C).

Ideally, the plan was to make B take a cert trusted between A and B, while C would take a cert valid between A and C.

Is there any way to do that?

I hope I explained the question well enough.

Comment: I believe this is very specific to the application you are talking about. Is this a known application or is it yours?

Answer (score 4):

The selection which certificate is send to the client is done at the TLS level based on the information in the ClientHello. Since there is no distinction in the ClientHello between these the clients B and C it is impossible to decide which of these certificates to serve based on these information.

Depending on the environment you are in and the server software you use you might be able to make this decision based on the IP address of the client. For example if your are able to divert the incoming connection to a specific local IP and port based on the source IP of the client you could then setup a server to provide different certificates and these ports. But, the exact setup depends on your environment and is off-topic here.